# Partition a partition before Linux Arch installation with GNU Parted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, arch-linux

I am booting Linux Arch-ISO and RTFM but could not find my special state in the beginner’s guide and other sides of the Arch-wiki.

I have a hard drive `sdb` and want to divide the partition `sdb2` (which is actually 80G) into two parts with 60G and 20G. I allready did the following:

```
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 512B 100%
```

But when I print the sdb informations with

```
parted /dev/sdb print
```

It shows that there is no File system for sdb4 but:

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
```

So when I try:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb4
```

I get this information:

```
Device size reported to be zero. Invalid partition specified, or table wasn’t reread after running `fdisk`, due to a modified partition being busy and in use.
```

Well I do not need this partition, but I created it first with low size so I can shrink the partition `sdb2` and growing the partition `sdb4` and use one as a swap and the other one for the system.

Additional information:

```
Partition table: msdos
```

Is this a name or a type of the partition table?

It may also be important for an answer to know that on another partition `sdb3` Windows is installed.

So how can I grow `sdb4` to 20G and shrink `sdb2` to 60G (already 80G) without effecting the other partitions?

Comment: All of these issues re nicely dealt with in Arch Linux's excellent wiki, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning

Answer (score 0):

The arch-wiki which is wrong in my case. So here is the thing:

If somebody wants to shrink a partition and use the new free size for another new partition instead of create the new partition first, do the following:

1. Choose the harddisk with an existing file-system:

   ```
   parted /dev/sdX
   ```

X stands for a letter (for instance ...sda). You should be in parted-mode

```
(parted)
```

2. Use print to get disk informations:

   ```
   print
   ```

Now you can see all partitions with START / END - Value which important. Imagine a pie diagram with 100% is the max size of the disk. The parts of the pie have START-Value and an END-Value which represents the degrees of the pie chart with the size entity. So we shrink the partition by shift the END-Value to a lower angle.

3. Shrink the partition

   ```
   (parted) resizepart PartNumber NewEndValue
   ```

   example:

   ```
   (parted) resizepart 1 10.0GB
   ```

The NewEndValue must be smaller as the original. Then you must have an undefined area of space for example

```
  Number  Start    End ...
   1      1049kB   10.0GB
   2      20.0GB   30.0GB
```

4. Now you can create a new partition from 10.0GB to 20.0GB:

   ```
   (parted) mkpart PART-TYPE FS-TYPE START END
   ```

   example:

   ```
   (parted) mkpart primary ext4 10.0GB 20.0GB
   ```

Comment: Nice rehash of the wiki.